# std function lower bound is not working as expected?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a method to return the closest value to 0.5, and used std::lower_bound. Why does this return the incorrect value, and a value that isn't even in the array? Worse, if I run it multiple times in a row it returns different answers. All I can think is it's in some way related to floats and decimal points but I can't pin it down. Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>       
#include <vector> 


int test() {


float array[] = {0.730453, 0.699215, 0.669218, 0.637146, 0.604049, 0.572716, 0.541121, 0.50986, 0.47848, 0.449675, 0.419725, 0.3908, 0.363951, 0.338627, 0.312707, 0.289863, 0.26578, 0.244605, 0.224265, 0.204569, 0.185969, 0.169755, 0.155114, 0.140401, 0.126714, 0.115817, 0.104347, 0.0945466, 0.000119226, 9.53812e-05, 9.53812e-05, 7.15359e-05};   
std::vector<float> v(std::begin(array),std::end(array));
std::reverse(std::begin(array),std::end(array));
std::vector<float>::iterator low, up;
low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 0.5);

std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
std::cout<<"index of thing is "<<low- v.begin()<<endl;
float & element = v[low- v.begin()];
std::cout<<"element closest to 0.5 is "<< element<<endl;
return 0;

            }
```

Comment: @cigien It has suggested values ranging from 2.01787e-43 to -3.73011e15, although always at position 32 i.e. the last in the vector. So std::lower_bound is only suitable for integers? It worked ok when I tested it for two decimal places but of course these are much longer...

Comment: `std::lower_bound ` requires that your vector is sorted with `<`. It's not the case.

Comment: @Caduchon Oops! I think my code should reverse read std::reverse(std::begin(v)...) instead of having array in the reverse function, let me see if that helps

Comment: @user13948 instead of reversing all your range, use `rbegin()` and `rend()` iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector needs to be sorted for `lower_bound` to return the correct result. If it's not sorted, then calling `lower_bound` invokes undefined behavior.

So before calling `lower_bound`, you need to do:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/gz-96g).

It seems that `array` is sorted in reverse order. So *before* constructing `v` you need to reverse `array`, not *after*.:

```
std::reverse(std::begin(array),std::end(array));  // first reverse
std::vector<float> v(std::begin(array),std::end(array));
```

Then there is no need to sort `v`.

Also, instead of reversing the `array` or `v`, you can just use reverse iterators:

```
std::lower_bound (v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0.5);
```

or use a different predicate:

```
std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 0.5, std::greater{});
```

Comment: @Caduchon I'm not sure what you mean. Is there a more efficient way to get `lower_bound` to work?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` uses `std::less` to compare, not the equality.

Comment: no. But there is more efficient ways to find the closest value.

Comment: @Caduchon Ok, but that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: But it is already sorted? Just reversed. Maybe then just `std::lower_bound (v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0.5);`?

Comment: At the time I post this, the `array` is not sorted. See the first three values.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, added options for that as well, thanks.

Comment: @Caleth Oops, you are right. I misread the 2nd and 3rd entry.

Comment: @cigien : the first sentence of the OP is "I'm trying to get a method to return the closest value to 0.5"

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggested method to find the closest value in a range if you don't know if it's sorted or not:

```
template <typename Iterator>
double closest_to(Iterator begin, Iterator end, double value)
{
    double min_dist = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    double min_val;
    for(Iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        const double dist = fabs(*it - value);
        if(dist < min_dist)
        {
            min_dist = dist;
            min_val = *it;
        }
    }
    return min_val;
}
```

Then, use it like that:

```
std::cout << closest_to(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.5) << std::endl;
```

If you know that your range is sorted, it is faster with this implementation:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
double closest_to(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end, double value)
{
  ForwardIterator lb = std::lower_bound(begin, end, value);
  if(lb == begin)
    return *lb;
  Iterator prev = lb - 1;
  if(lb == end)
    return *prev;
  if(value - *prev < *lb - value)
    return *prev;
  else
    return *lb;
}
```

Comment: You can wrap std::min_element instead: `std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end(),[value = 0.5](auto a, auto b){ return std::abs(a-value) < std::abs(b-value)}`.

Comment: @MikaelH, from C++11 yes.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to remind yourself what a pain C++ was before lambdas: https://godbolt.org/z/357JTj.

Comment: @MikaelH: actually, I don't know the world after C++03. One of our clients requires compatibility with gcc 4.1 :-p

Answer (score 0):

your data needs to be ordered to use `lower_bound`. The default order is `<`, but you can specify a different ordering, such as `>` (via [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)).

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>       
#include <vector> 

int test() {

    float array[] = {0.730453, 0.699215, 0.669218, 0.637146, 0.604049, 0.572716, 0.541121, 0.50986, 0.47848, 0.449675, 0.419725, 0.3908, 0.363951, 0.338627, 0.312707, 0.289863, 0.26578, 0.244605, 0.224265, 0.204569, 0.185969, 0.169755, 0.155114, 0.140401, 0.126714, 0.115817, 0.104347, 0.0945466, 0.000119226, 9.53812e-05, 9.53812e-05, 7.15359e-05};   
    std::vector<float> v(std::begin(array),std::end(array));
    std::reverse(std::begin(array),std::end(array));
    std::vector<float>::iterator low, up;
    low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 0.5, std::greater<float>{});
    
    std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';
    std::cout<<"index of thing is "<<low- v.begin()<<std::endl;
    float & element = v[low- v.begin()];
    std::cout<<"element closest to 0.5 is "<< element<<std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```